# defer.promise returning same result in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, deferred

I have a Service which fetch the data from API.When I am trying to call this service. It's returning with same value.

```
appName.service('FetchCustomerDate', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var self = this;
    self.getCustomerData = function(token,name) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: ,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": token,
                "x-xcmc-auth": ''
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
            return deferred.promise;
        }, function(response) {
            deferred.reject(response);
            return deferred.promise;
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: What does "same value" mean? Right now, the `return deferred.promise` lines do nothing; just return the `$http` promise. No need for the deferred.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `return deferred.promise;` line outside the success and failure functions of `.then()` ?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan same value means API respond is same as pervious API call.

Comment: @JFBeaulieu I have tried to put "return deferred.promise;" outside the success and failure of ".then()", but got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a bit of confusion here. Let's try to clear it. If you want to use deferred object, you need to change your code a bit:

```
appName.service('FetchCustomerDate', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var self = this;
    self.getCustomerData = function (token, name) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({ // Do not return  here, you need to return the deferred.promise
            method: 'GET',
            url: '...some URL here...',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": token,
                "x-xcmc-auth": ''
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response); // It's correct, you are resolving the deferred promise here.
            // return deferred.promise; // You do not need to return the deferred.promise here.
        }, function (response) {
            deferred.reject(response); // It's correct, you are rejecting the deferred promise here.
            // return deferred.promise; // You do not need to return the deferred.promise here.
        });

        return deferred.promise; // The function must return the deferred.promise
    };
}]);
```

In detail, function `getCustomerData` must return the promise belonging to `deferred` object with `return deferred.promise`. Inside `then()` callback you simply resolve or reject `deferred` promise. You do not need to return the `deferred.promise`.

You can improve the code. The `$http` service returns a promise, and the value returned by `then` callbacks is wrapped by `then` method in a promise. Knowing that, you can remove the use of `deferred` object:

```
appName.service('FetchCustomerDate', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var self = this;
    self.getCustomerData = function (token, name) {
        return $http({ // Here, you need to return the promise returned by $http. Than promise will contain the response returned inside "then" callbacks.
            method: 'GET',
            url: '...some URL here...',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": token,
                "x-xcmc-auth": ''
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response; // Simply return the response, it will be wrapped in a resolved promise by "then()"
        }, function (response) {
            return response; // Simply return the response, it will be wrapped in a rejected promise by "then()"
        });
    };
}]);
```

As you can see, the 2 `then` callbacks simply returns the `response` object, for this reason you can omit them:

```
appName.service('FetchCustomerDate', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var self = this;
    self.getCustomerData = function (token, name) {
        return $http({ // Here, you need to return the promise returned by $http. Than promise will contain the response form the GET call
            method: 'GET',
            url: '...some URL here...',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": token,
                "x-xcmc-auth": ''
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you fetch data with the `$http`service, you want to obtain data from the response and affect it to the `$scope` for instance, or process it somehow. What are you trying to do? Please clarify your question.

Normally a fetch will look something like this:

```
appName.service('FetchCustomerDate', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var self = this;

    function notifyError(reason) {
      console.error(reason);
    }

    self.getCustomerData = function(token,name) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: ,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": token,
                "x-xcmc-auth": ''
            }
        })
          .then(function onSuccess(response) {
            var cfg = response.data; // process data 
        })
          .then(function onSuccess(response) {
            // chained promises
        })
          .then(
            function onSuccess(res) {
              // ... this will trigger the chain reaction
              deferred.resolve(res);
            },
            function onFailure(reason) {
              notifyError(reason); // manage the error
              deferred.reject(reason);
            })
          ;
          return deferred.promise;
        }
    }]);
```